# How do you connect 3/8 compression male hose to 1/4 filter tube (blue tube)?

Tags: plumbing-fixture

I have an under-sink filter that I try to connect to the water tap; filter has a 3/8" compression male end while the tap has 1/4" (OD) blue hose. Any advice appreciated in advance.

Comment: Might need an adapter/reducer,expander.  Tubing to hose sizes can be weird and I do not think you use compression fittings on hoses, they are too soft.  Picture of what you have will help the plumbing people on here.

Answer (score 2):

There is not much information provided in your question, and photos would help greatly. But if I were to guess, you need an adaptor to transition from 'push-to-connect' (the 1/4 OD blue hose) to 3/8 compression. This could be done a few different ways, but the best bet is to head over to a plumbing or big box hardwood store and see what they have available.

Below is a [1/4" push-to-connect x 1/2" MIP adaptor](https://www.lowes.com/pd/SharkBite-1-4-in-Push-to-Connect-x-1-2-in-Mip-dia-Male-Adapter-Push-Fitting/1000192601). You could then use a 3/8" compression x 1/2" FIP adaptor or a 1/2" brass coupling with a 3/8" compression x 1/2" MIP adaptor to complete the transition. It all depends on what's available, and it's best to bring the hose to the store with you and ask for assistance.

[image]